# How to get mass normalized mode shapes?

Tags: dynamics, vibration, modal-analysis, eigenvalue-analysis

I have an MDOF system with 4 degrees of freedom with forced input at one of the dof (4th dof)(it is a sinusoidal wave with a particular frequency expected to be generated using a shaker); displacement response is measured for this system. I would like to extract mode shapes for this system experimentally, but in order to achieve this objective I took up a theoretical case for understanding various complications and problems in it. So, now my system can be represented as:

> \begin{equation}
> G_{YY}=H G_{YX}
> \end{equation}
>   \begin{Bmatrix}
> Y_{1}\\ 
> Y_{2}\\ 
> Y_{3}\\ 
> Y_{4}
> \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
> H_{11} & H_{12} & H_{13} & H_{14}\\ 
> H_{21} & H_{22} & H_{23} & H_{24}\\ 
> H_{31} & H_{32} & H_{33} & H_{34}\\ 
> H_{41} & H_{42} & H_{43} & H_{44}& 
> \end{bmatrix}
>   \begin{Bmatrix}
> 0\\ 
> 0\\ 
> 0\\ 
> X_{4}
> \end{Bmatrix}

Here H is the Frequency Response Function (FRF) and it can be seen that only one column would be needed to obtain the mode shapes of the system. Now, writing a code on matlab give me:

```
> FRF(i,:)=GYY./GYX
> plot(fr,abs(real(GYY./GYX)))
```

The amplitudes and shapes could be extracted from the above expressions, but my concern is on obtaining mass normalized mode shapes, i.e. 
\begin{equation}
\phi^{T}\left[M_A\right]\phi=I
\end{equation}
If I am not wrong, it should be possible in the case of input + output experimental modal analysis. I know that there would be many complications but at least in the case of a theoretical case it should come right. I generated a code for the above case by using mdof equations of motion for a  4dof MDOF system:

This is what I am supposed to get, as verified with eigen analysis of the mass M and stiffness K matrices:

```
   -0.1442    0.3651    0.4152   -0.2710
   -0.2710    0.3651   -0.1442    0.4152
   -0.3651   -0.0000   -0.3651   -0.3651
   -0.4152   -0.3651    0.2710    0.1442
```

But from the frf the the first mode shape is extracted to be:

```
0.0098
0.0186
0.0254
0.0296
```

It looks porportional with the actual one but is not scaled to the real values to satisfy mass normalization.
Where am I going wrong?